# Table inside Block Element. What Rules applied

Tags: css

Can someone explain why div with the red border not expanded?

```
<body style="padding:200px">
      <div style="border:1px solid red"> 
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <input type="text" style="width:1600px"/>
                </tr>        
             </table>  
      </div>  
<body>
```

I do not want another solution, i want to learn what css box sizing rules applied by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The `div` with the red border *does* expand, its width however is constrained by the `body`. Because it has no specified width wider than the body, it does not overflow it.

The `input` on the other hand has a specified width wider than the body so it *overflows*.

```
<body style="padding:200px">
      <div style="border:1px solid red"> 
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" style="width:1600px"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>        
             </table>  
      </div>  
<body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mz8N8/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer...Its my first question on Stackoverflow but i've read 100000 answers 10 years now.

The main problem is that a have a Fieldset element (block element) in the body and inside the fieldset i have a table grid width 20 ore more columns and cell have one and only one text box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer...Its my first question on Stackoverflow but i've read 100000 answers 10 years now.

The main problem is that a have a Fieldset element (block elemt) in the body and inside the fieldset i have a table grid width 20 ore more columns and cell have one and only one text box.

The table's width keeps growing outside the fieldset and the fieldset (because it has a bacground color) seems corrupted.

I tried to hack the fieldset - like making display:inline, to force to expand and include all the table,BUT i want a solution width no or overriding  browsers default css rules

Comment: Please post the relevant code (in your question) and use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show the result.